# Iterate through list to insert into SQLite Table

Tags: asp.net, sqlite

I am retrieving a list of service calls using an AJAX call to web service.  I need to iterate through each service call returned by the web service and insert it into a SQLite table.  I am struggling with the timing in my loop.  For example, if there are two service calls, two lines will be inserted into the table but both will be the data from the second call.  I have tried moving my variable declaration and value assignments around and if they are inside the transaction then all the fields come back undefined.  Outside the transaction and all lines insert as the last record.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "MyService.asmx/GetCalls",
    data: '{ user:"' +  user +'"}',
    success: function (data) {
        saveCalls(data.d);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert("Retrieve Calls: " + err.Message);
    }
});

function saveCalls(result) {
   var insertString = "Insert Into Calls Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   var call, po, adrsCode, status, dispDate, dispTime, desc, customer, address, city, state, zip, phone, equipment, tracking, srvType, statDesc;

   $.each(result, function () {
       call = this.CallNumber;
       po = this.PoNumber;
       adrsCode = this.AdrsCode;
       status = this.Status;
       dispDate = this.DispatchedDate;
       dispTime = this.DispatchedTime;
       desc = this.Description;
       customer = this.Customer;
       address = this.Address;
       city = this.City;
       state = this.State;
       zip = this.Zip;
       phone = this.Phone;
       equipment = this.Equipment;
       tracking = this.Tracking;
       srvType = this.SrvType;
       statDesc = this.StatDesc;
       db.transaction(function (tx) {

          tx.executeSql(insertString, [call, po, adrsCode, status, dispDate, dispTime, desc, customer, address,
            city, state, zip, phone, equipment, tracking, srvType, statDesc],
            onSqlSuccess, onSqlError);

    });
});
```

}

EDIT: Code that worked for those who have the same issue:

```
function saveCalls(result) {
   var insertString = "Insert Into Calls(CallNumber, PoNumber, AdrsCode, SrvStat, DispatchDate, DispatchTime, SvcDescription, CustNmbr, Address, "
            + "City, State, Zip, Phone, Equipment, Tracking, SrvType, StatDesc) ";

   $.each(result, function () {

       insertString = insertString + "Select '{0}' as CallNumber,'{1}' as PoNumber,'{2}' as AdrsCode,'{3}' as SrvStat,'{4}' as DispatchDate,'{5}' as DispatchTime,'{6}' as SvcDescription,'{7}' as CustNmbr,'{8}' as Address,'{9}' as City,'{10}' as State,'{11}' as Zip,'{12}' as Phone,'{13}' as Equipment,'{14}' as Tracking,'{15}' as SrvType,'{16}' as StatDesc Union "
                    .format(this.CallNumber, this.PoNumber, this.AdrsCode, this.Status, this.DispatchedDate, this.DispatchedTime,
                        this.Description, this.Customer, this.Address, this.City, this.State, this.Zip, this.Phone, this.Equipment, 
                        this.Tracking, this.SrvType, this.StatDesc);

   });

   db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(insertString.substring(0, insertString.length - 6), [],
        onSqlSuccess, onSqlError);
   });
```

}

Comment: Found the answer.  Will mark as answered as soon as required time period has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see additional code added to original post for anyone struggling with the same issue.